# Simple Question About the jQuery Datepicker's Calendar Icon

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Sorry for the simple question.

I'm using a jQuery DatePicker. I want the little calendar icon to appear next to the text input area. I'm using the Smoothness jQuery UI theme.

Does jQuery UI include the calendar.gif icon (not the datepicker itself, but just the little icon)? If not, can you suggest where I can get a free small calendar.gif?

As I understand it, I add the calendar as follows: 
    buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif'

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the built in icons from jQuery UI; there is a calendar icon. The code is something like:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button'
}).next('button').text('').button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-calendar'
    },
    text: false
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/rrcmq/.

It is inspired by this article: http://www.somethinghitme.com/2010/10/06/use-built-in-jquery-ui-icon-with-datepicker/.

Answer (score 1):

I far as I know it does not. I provided my own when I used the datepicker with one but I already had an icon.

You can google it but there are some free icons here: http://findicons.com/search/calendar

Comment: Hi @jk., Thank you for the link. I voted +1 as I probably will go with a custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to JQueryUI site then click Demo and choose Dateicker and select icon trigger example. You will on this [page(datepicker icon-trigger example)](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger), and the page will look like below picture.
[image]

Now you right click on the calendar icon marked by yellow and download it by choose "Save Image As..." and include it in your project than `buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif'` will work fine.